# Add ViewPagerIndicator Library Project to my Project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, viewpagerindicator

The ViewPagerIndicator open source project is useful in android apps for indicating which viewpager page the user is currently viewing. I want to add this open source project to the project that I am currently working on. My question is, how do i do this? Should I take out the individual files needed from ViewPagerIndicator and add them to my project? Should I import the entire viewpagerindicator project into my project? What is the normal practice for using open source projects like this? It should be noted that viewpagerindicator is not and cannot be a standalone jar file according to their github page.

Comment: Its an Android library project.  You want to include it as such, rather than take the files and add them to your project (you can do that, but its not recommended).  It can't be a jar because it has resources, and jars don't.  Android really needs to come up with an enhanced jar format that allows resource files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to File > Project Structure > Modules > clicked + sign > Import modules, then chose the project. I had to delete the sample part and keep only the library part. I also had to remove a android support jar, and then when I had compile errors, I had to do whatever android studio told me was a solution with the red light bulb.

Comment: there is no option of import module there is only new module means (create new)...